# Button Group Click Handler - How to get text content of clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up two button groups. A click on any button in the second group should add a new button to the first group. The new button shall get the same label as the clicked button.

`var name = this.textContent` works if the click handler is attached to a single button. How do you get the text content of the clicked button when the click handler is instead attached to a group of buttons?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="group1">
    <button> nameA </button>
    <button> nameB </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="group2">
    <button> nameC </button>
    <button> nameD </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#group2').on('click', function(event) {
  var name = this.textContent   // wrong!
  var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + name + '">');
  $("div#group1").append(r);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bogl/e5Lq4jjj/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$('#group2').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  var name = this.textContent
  var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + name + '">');
  $("div#group1").append(r);
});
```

Second parameter in 'on' method can be selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.
Check this https://jsfiddle.net/q6b6g3xm/

Answer (score 2):

In your case, this should be enought:

```
$('#group2 button').click(function(event) {
  var name = this.textContent
  var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + name + '">');
  $("div#group1").append(r);
});
```

Prefer the RobHil solution if you other buttons will be created in #group2 after the execution of the jQuery code.

Else, I see two other possibilities:

```
$('#group2 button').each(function () {
  var $button = $(this).click(function(event) {
    var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + $button.text() + '">');
    $("div#group1").append(r);
  });
});
```

or:

```
$('#group2').click(function(event) {
  var $button = $(event.target);
  var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + $button.text() + '">');
  $("div#group1").append(r);
});
```

But keep in mind the target depend on where you click if you have nested blocks in the clicked zone: https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: I would prefer the second approach and would use the `event.stopPropagation()` to avoid any bubbling :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own approach to the problem. I modified HTML code a little by adding individual `id` to the buttons.

HTML:

```
<div id="group1" >
    <button id="btn-A">nameA</button>
    <button id="btn-B">nameB</button>
    <button id="btn-C">nameC</button>
</div>
    <hr />
<div id="group2">
    <button id="btn-D">nameD</button>
    <button id="btn-E">nameE</button>
    <button id="btn-F">nameF</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
             // click on the button
            $(document).on('click','button', function(){

                //store the value of the id and
                //  split it @ '-' into array ['btn','A']
                $id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');

                // store the value at index 1 into $id
                $id = $id[1];

                //get the Id of the current div group
                $divId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');

                //check which div group is current and
                //Assign the reversed value as appropriate
                if($divId === "group1"){
                    $addId = "#group2";

                }else {
                    $addId = "#group1";
                }

                //Remove the button from the group
                $(this).remove();

                //Add the button to the second div group
                $($addId).append('<button id="btn-'+$id+'">'+$(this).text()+'</button>');

            });
```